# run tsc with nodemon not working when file changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I installed nodemon and typescript

this is my start script
`"start": "nodemon --watch '*/**.ts' --exec tsc && node dist/app.js",`
what can be wrong above? it can be started but not re-executing when the file changed.

I also tried
`"start": "nodemon --watch '*/**.ts' --exec tsc && node dist/app.js",`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you need to specify [the extension](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon?activeTab=readme#specifying-extension-watch-list) nodemon should watch, the correct call would be `nodemon --watch '*/**.ts' -e ts --exec tsc && node dist/app.js`.

Although you are not going to have the app executed as the first command does not finish, so the `node dist/app.js` part won't be executed.

I would recommend [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all) for this setup:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm-run-all dev:*",
    "dev:watch": "nodemon --watch '*/**.ts' -e ts --exec tsc",
    "dev:run": "nodemon --watch dist/app.js --exec 'node dist/app.js'"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate your effort and want to provide you a simple alternative that works.

Steps you need to follow:

- Initialize a Nodejs project using `npm` or `yarn`
- Install typescript and nodemon as devDependency in your project.
- Configure your `package.json` file to do the stuff for you.
- Create a `tsconfig.json` file (optional but believe me it helps in your project)

#### Step 1 (Project Setup)

Execute the commands in your terminal.

```sh
# Create project directory
mkdir sample 

# Change in your project directory
cd sample

# Intitialize nodejs project
npm init -y
```

#### Step 2 (Dependency Setup)

Execute the below commands to install nodemon and typescript

```sh
# Install nodemon and typescript
npm install --save-dev nodemon typescript

# Optional (If you like to use intellisense for nodejs modules)
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

#### Step 3: (Configure package.json file)

Before configuring our `package.json` file, here is my idea:

```
.
├── dist # Compiled Typescript files to Javascript Files (output directory) 
├── src # We will write typescript here.
├── node_modules
├── package.json
```

We will write all our typescript in `src/` folder and `index.ts` will be entrypo

Here is our `package.json` file

```json
{
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple typescript setup",
+ "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
+   "start": "node dist/index.js",
+   "watch": "tsc --watch",
+   "build": "tsc",
+   "dev": "nodemon"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Jayant Malik",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2"
  }
}
```

#### Step 4 (tsconfig.json)

```sh
# Create tsconfig.json file
touch tsconfig.json
```

Here is the content of the `tsconfig.json` file.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "es2017",
      :"ESNext",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "importNotUsedAsValues": "remove",
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "charset": "utf-8",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./src",
    "./src/**/*.tsx",
    "./src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

#### Step 5: (Running Instructions)

You can open multiple terminal tabs for the below actions.

Terminal Tab 1

```sh
# Start your development server (nodemon)
npm run dev
```

Terminal Tab 2

```sh
# Start typescript server
npm run watch
```

So, you will have a clean and simple project that will work.

Comment: where is the nodemon part?

Comment: Nodemon will monitor your javascript files compiled by tsc compiler. You can use `npm run dev` command for that.